# First character indent

Tags: indentation

My document begins like this:

```
first line\newline
second line\newline
third line
```

First characters of the first and second lines are indented?
Could somebody explain me why?

Actuallt there was some code between first and second line for placing background. Yeas it is indented cause the start of paragraph, which I avoided using \noindent.

Comment: Leave an empty line between two paragraphs to get the default spacing. To break the line without indentation, use `first line\\second line`.

Comment: Please post a complete small document that shows the problem, it is impossible to tell from the fragment what you are seeing

Comment: @Sigur `\newline` is equivalent to `\\ ` but the OP claims the second line is indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code you show, only the first line will be indented, as the start of a paragraph:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

first line\newline
second line\newline
third line

\end{document}
```